# Create Full AWS RDS Snapshot

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Can I create a full database snapshot or backup (manual/automated) for Amazon RDS Postgres Databases and not incremental ones. I want to create a job that provides full database parquet files everyday and share it with the Data warehousing team.

The document [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) says the following:

> The first snapshot of a DB instance contains the data for the full DB instance. Subsequent snapshots of the same DB instance are incremental, which means that only the data that has changed after your most recent snapshot is saved.

Comment: Hey Marcin, we ended up creating a lambda for a quick solution. AWS Glue looked promising, but it did not let us select clusters though, it shows a list of databases only. So we have two environments (dev & qa) on the same AWS account having the same database name with different clusters, it would not work in this case. Also we were not able to see a list of tables when selecting our database. Hence we implemented a lambda with AWSSDK for quick implementation. Thanks for your help though :).

Answer (score 2):

The RDS snapshots do not create Parquet files, as they are based on [EBS snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html).

To get Parquet files the best way would be to setup a [Glue job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/author-job.html) which can run automatically on your [schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-data-warehouse-schedule.html).

Comment: I should have mentioned RDS snapshot when exported to S3 gives out parquet file per object (table)

Comment: @shaikhspear Then what's wrong with those parquet files? They are incomplete?

Comment: every new snapshot only has the incremental data (that changed since the last snapshot was taken). Only the first snapshot is a full database snapshot. I want to find a way to generate Full data snapshots for every export.

Comment: @shaikhspear If you copy snaphot to a different region, it will be full.